# Possible combinations of pandas columns from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations

I have a pandas dataframe in python, with the following structure:

| Date | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 10:00:00 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 11:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 12:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 13:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

This is a snippet of my real dataframe, which has lots of "letter" columns (more than 100). My problem is that I need to obtain the sum of the numbers for each datetime and letter for different combinations.

This was answered in [All possible combinations as new columns of a dataframe based on primary column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215221/all-possible-combinations-as-new-columns-of-a-dataframe-based-on-primary-column), but it computes all possible combinations from N to M elements. For a df of 100 columns, all possible combinations from 1 sigle letter column to the full combined 100 is madness and impossible to compute.

Fortunately, I am only interested in certain combinations (again, ca. 50 in the real df), which are given in a list:

list_possibilities = ['A+B',  'A+B+D',  'B+D+E+G',  'F+H',  'D+E+F+G+H',  'D',  'F',  'G+H']

As you can see, single columns such as "D" or "F" may also be a possibility. So the final df would be fairly compact, and wouldn't need a brute-force computation of thousands of combinations (here shown only for the first two rows for simplicity):

| Date | A+B | A+B+D | B+D+E+G | F+H | D+E+F+G+H | D | F | G+H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 4 | 8 | 8 | 1 | 6 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 7 | 12 | 2 | 2 | 8 |

Knowing the prior structure of the combinations allows to exponentially decrease the combinations and sums pandas must do, but I am unable to generalize the previous code of the solution to this case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) in a dictionary comprehension:

```
out = (pd
   .concat({cols: df.set_index('Date')[cols.split('+')].sum(axis=1)
            for cols in list_possibilities}, axis=1)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
                  Date  A+B  A+B+D  B+D+E+G  F+H  D+E+F+G+H  D  F  G+H
0  2022-01-01 10:00:00    4      8        8    1          6  4  0    1
1  2022-01-01 11:00:00    1      3        6    7         12  2  2    8
2  2022-01-01 12:00:00    2      3        3    1          2  1  1    0
3  2022-01-01 13:00:00    0      0        1    5          6  0  3    3
4  2022-01-02 10:00:00    3      4       10    5         12  1  4    5
5  2022-01-02 11:00:00    0      0        5    0          5  0  0    5
6  2022-01-02 12:00:00    0      0        7    7         14  0  4    8
7  2022-01-02 13:00:00    0      1        4    0          4  1  0    0
```

Comment: This is a very elegant and efficient solution. Thank you very much for your help!